# Shape of FX Volatility Surface

Tags: options, volatility, fx

I'm familiar with the volatility surface for equity options with the smile/skew dynamic and flattening with increased maturity, and the explanation/intuition behind its shape. However, today I came across the volatility surface for FX options, and I noticed that, unlike equity options, volatility is increasing with maturity. I would like to understand what the reasoning for this is. I could not find anything in e.g. Wystrup (2006), and my best guess is uncertainty about the future interest rate differential. Is this guess right? Are there other sources?

Comment: Could you give some more info on what you're looking at? Which FX pair? How are you looking at that vol? Using strikes or delta? Do you mean the implied vol or the local vol?

Comment: Hi. Implied vol surface with deltas. I checked multiple FX pairs - here are a few I remember off the top of my head: EURUSD, EURJPY, USDGBP, USDCAD, and AUDNZD. They all had the same dynamic wrt. maturity. 

I checked the surfaces on Refinitiv, but here's a similar example from a paper (albeit with moneyness).
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Average-implied-volatility-surface-from-EUR-USD-options-for-the-period_fig1_228888445